# How to get element calling function in Vue (no event)

Tags: vue.js

I have this code and I need to have the calling div on the getWidth function. Is this possible? Since it's not an event I'm not sure how this can be handled. Generally I'd do `$event` but it doesn't exist in this context.

```
<div :style="{width: getWidth($this_element)}">
</div>
```

This is contained in a `v-for` loop.

Comment: You can simply use a `ref` on the div and pass it to your function.

Comment: How do I access them later? this.$refs[id] works, but how do I acess the width with that? I tried this.$refs[id].clientWidth but that returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

The current DOM element is already available in `getWidth()` via [`this.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el). If you wanted to access the element's width in JavaScript, you could do something like this:

```
<template>
  <div :style="{width: getWidth()}">...</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    getWidth() {
      return (this.$el.clientWidth * .33) + 'px';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    getWidth() {
      return (this.$el.clientWidth * .33) + 'px';
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.my-el {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="my-el" :style="{width: getWidth()}">{{getWidth()}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm running Nuxt and can't get this to work. this.$el returns the global DOM

Comment: What do you mean by "global DOM"? Can you provide a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?